Flutter web hosted from firebase and did the forwarding from hostinger but it shows not secure connection error
When I run my app directly from the debug console or using the link provided in the terminal, everything works fine. However, when I try to open it from the .com domain, I get an error:
This site can’t provide a secure connection. www.aiderahtech.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
This issue only occurs on Safari and not on Chrome.

It's working fine now? but it's showing just a blank white page. Also the SSL issue was because the SSL certificates generated by firebase did not include your Domain name.

nope its not working fine, how to add firebase generated ssl
